# handling back pressure with mongoose while retrieving documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose, stream, highland.js

I'm using highland to handle back pressure. My code is:

```
const pipeline = [{
            $match: { 'published': true, status: 'Approved' }
        }];

        const cursor = UserModel.aggregate(pipeline)
            .cursor().exec();

        // iterating over each hospitality one by one    
        highland(cursor)
            .map((doc) => {
                // some code
                return doc;
            })
            .map((doc) => {
                // some code
                return doc;
            })
            .map((doc) => {
                // some code
                return doc;
            })
            .errors(function (err) {
                winston.error('error', err);
            })
            .done(() => {
                winston.info('JOB: done');
            });
```

I want one document to fetch then process through map's streams one by one.

I'm not sure if this would handle backpressure because [highland](https://highlandjs.org/) doc say:

Please see Back-pressure section into the highland doc.

> Some streams (such as those based on events) cannot be paused. In
>   these cases data is buffered until the consumer is ready to handle it.

Please suggest any other way if this does not handle backpressure!